# og:image sometimes works, sometimes not

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I need support in order to the tag "og:image", it not worked properly for a week. Sometimes Facebook will show the thumbnail, but other times it won't. I also tried to clean the cache with the debug tool but it didn't fix the issue.

Here an example of my code:

http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">

...

Answer (score 0):

Do you also include og:image:secure_url ?